# Can't able to use condition inside of loop (using describe_instances)

Tags: python, boto3

I am trying to learn boto3 library and started to do some experiment by myself. The issue is i am using describe_instances method and i can get the information of my instances. So far i have not any problem. But when i put a condition that if an instance have specific IAM role then i wanted to add this instance id to list. But it returns me an empty list. What is my mistake here ? Thanks.

```
ec2_client=boto3.client("ec2")

def describe_instances():
    resp = ec2_client.describe_instances()
    print(resp)

    instance_ids=[]

    for reservations in resp["Reservations"]:
        for instances in reservations["Instances"]:
            if instances["IamInstanceProfile"]=={'Arn': 'arn:aws:iam::723149566365:instance-profile/PublicEC2_S3Access'}:
                instance_ids.append(instances["InstanceId"])


    print(instance_ids)
```

Comment: Please be a bit more specific: How are you using the `describe_instances` function? Do you want to `print` the list? I think simply returning the list will do, i.e., just put `return instance_ids` at the end of the function.

Comment: I was just doing some basic function and doesnt require any returns. In below entry fixed my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to boto3 [docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_instances), the `IamInstanceProfile` element is a `dict` which contains 2 keys:

- *Arn* - string
- *Id* - string

So when you compare `instances["IamInstanceProfile"]` to a dict with only `Arn` key, it always be `False`.

I would suggest you to change your check to be:

```
my_arn = 'arn:aws:iam::723149566365:instance-profile/PublicEC2_S3Access'
for reservations in resp["Reservations"]:
        for instances in reservations["Instances"]:
            if instances["IamInstanceProfile"]["Arn"] == my_arn:
                instance_ids.append(instances["InstanceId"])
```

Comment: Thank you this is solved my problem.. But i have also found out that instead of "Instance Profile ARNs" i have copied the "Role ARN" by mistake :) I have also fixed that thing and now it works. Thanks..

Comment: Cool! Happy to help :)

Comment: Oooo you went deep. Great post!